# Accessing file in Virtual Directory on IIS7.5 in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, server-side-includes

I have a file called index.asp in my application under the below structure MyApp/Admin/index.asp

This file has an entry

```
<!--#INCLUDE VIRTUAL="/dbinfo/MyFile.asp"-->
```

I have a virtual Directory created at the MyApp level in IIS7.5 and I can see the MyFile.asp in the dbinfo virtual directory. However when I access it in the code I am getting the below error in the IIS Logs:

GET /MyApp/Admin/index.asp |30|ASP_0126|Include_file_not_found 80

This code works just fine in IIS6.0. We need to upgrade to 7.5 now and are running into this issue. When I place the file in the same directory as my code and access it as below it works just fine.

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="MyFile.asp"-->
```

Below is my web.config fine for reference.

```
<configuration>  
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>  
    <system.web>        
        <compilation debug="true" />
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
        <identity impersonate="false" />    
    </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

Please advise.

Comment: Is "enable parent paths" set to true?  http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default

Comment: I would do the same thing as @John suggests. Check that 'enable parent paths' in IIS -> ASP settings is set to TRUE

Comment: Yes. It is set to True.

Comment: This seems somewhat strange but restarting the IIS Server seemed to address the issue.